# Cache Busting in Angular 12

Tags: angular, tomcat, caching

I am trying to implement cache-busting in Angular 12. I have read a lot of solutions on the web including StackOverflow also but nothing is working.

I have Deployed my application on the Tomcat server. Whenever I deploy newer code on the server the client has to hard refresh the browser to receive new changes otherwise it starts to fetch files from the disk cache. I have tried some of the options:

1. creating production build using --output-hashing=all property.
2. Interceptor for HTTP requests and add no-cache header in it.
3. Add no-cache in the index.html file.
4. Add ?v=versionnumber at the end of each script tag in the index.html file.

but none of them are working properly. If anyone has implemented the same please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build your code for production with Angular CLI?
Production builds for Angular automatically create unique Javascript and CSS file names to bust caches.

As a result, your problem will be solved if you run

```
ng build --configuration=production
```

when building for prod.

Comment: Yes, I always make the build using the same but sometimes it returns the same hash if it is a minor change. Many peoples have faced the same issue over time you can check the this link for the same https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10641

Comment: That issue was with Angular 6 and was closed two years ago. The current version of Angular is 12. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using Angular 12 but the same issue persists in this also. This issue is never resolved they just market it inactive.

Comment: How many files are impacted? If it's just one or two, couldn't a manual update of the file name do the trick? It's not ideal but it's a super easy workaround.

Comment: Found the problem with my deployment method. I used to only replace the folder without restarting the server. After I started restarting the system after every deployment all the issues related to caching are resolved.